# Business level IP's can't pass reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, redirect, proxy, recaptcha

I have a simple script which is included on every page of a website which detects proxies and redirects proxy users to a reCAPTCHA. Unfortunately our own business computers cannot pass the reCAPTCHA, it just keeps refreshing the image no matter how many times the correct codes are entered. Strangely, I can from my Virgin media connection connect through a web based proxy and pass the reCAPTCHA first time and get redirected to the website index page with no further issues. Also tried this with a Sky internet connection using a web proxy and had no problems. It seems only some businesses are having problems passing the reCAPTCHA.

**Here's the detect and redirect PHP code:**

```
<?php
if(@fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errstr, $errno, 1))
echo "<script>window.open('http://bellsdomestics.co.uk/check','_self')</script>";
?>
```

**Here's the code to the page you get redirected to if you're using a proxy:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
require_once('site/php/recaptchalib.php');
// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = " publickeyhidden";
$privatekey = " privatekeyhidden";
# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;
# was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if ($resp->is_valid) {
echo "<script>window.open('http://bellsdomestics.co.uk','_self')</script>";
} else {
# set the error code so that we can display it
$error = $resp->error;
}
}
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
<br/>
<input type='submit' value='submit' class='bttn3' />
</form>
```

The code for the library was downloaded directly from this url: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest
Finally, I spoke to the business vendor for our internet connection who are http://www.gamma.co.uk/ and sibling company Lily Comms communications. Lily Comms refused to accept they had a proxy server in front of the static IP we have.
Have any of you come across this problem and been able to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: check cookies, check sessions, session ids, etc...

Comment: I'm curious, why are you suppressing errors?

Comment: If either of you are behind a proxy, do you have a problem passing the reCAPTCHA?